# How to refresh FigureCanvasTkAgg continuously in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to automatically update a chart in tkinter continuously using FigureCanvasTkAgg without the use of buttons.

Here is what I've coded so far

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root = tk.Tk()

def cplot():
    xCord = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(5)]
    yCord = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(5)]

    #defining heatmap dimensions
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    #ploting heat map with x and y coordinates
    sb.kdeplot(xCord, yCord, shade = True, cmap = "Reds")
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()

    root.after(1, cplot)
    return fig
    
fig = cplot()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    
root.after(1, cplot)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're calling `return` before `after` which will never be called, Switch the order of those statements.

Comment: @Mike67 I swapped the positions of those 2 lines of codes. The charts refresh automatically now, however tkinter only displays the first chart and does not update it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

To have the plot image regenerate on a timer, recreate the canvas widget inside the function and recall the function.

Try this code:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = None

def cplot():
    global canvas
    xCord = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(5)]
    yCord = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(5)]

    #defining heatmap dimensions
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    #ploting heat map with x and y coordinates
    sb.kdeplot(xCord, yCord, shade = True, cmap = "Reds")
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    plt.axis("off")
    
    if canvas: canvas.get_tk_widget().pack_forget()  # remove previous image
    
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    
    root.after(100, cplot)
        
root.after(1, cplot)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `pack_forget()` function before, thanks for your solution!